# restricted :Unable to redirect output

Tags: shell

I logged in to rbash using `chsh` command. Though,I have logged out from rbash but still I am unable to execute various commands like `cd` , `output redirection` commands etc . When I executed this command `cat > jmf` . I got this result:-

```
rbash: jmf: restricted: cannot redirect output.
```

Could any one please tell me where am I going wrong??

Answer (score 1):

`chsh` is not used to "log in" to anything. It's used to change your login shell (done by altering the relevant field in the passwd file. If you changed it to `rbash`, your login shell is restricted. Change it back to `bash` and you can your redirections and such to work.

Comment: I changed back to bash using chsh command . But Change is reflected only after I restart Ubuntu again. Could you please tell me why is it so??

Comment: You don't need to restart Ubuntu. You just need to log out and log in again.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error from another route. I use 'bash -vx' to execute a script when I want to see commands as the script is running. I accidentally specified 'bash -rx' and got the error mentioned in the title since the script was doing something restricted. As I recall it was trying to redirect stdout to a file in /tmp.